# url.resolve() with more than two arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using `url.resolve()` to join components of a url from a config file like so:

```
var uri = url.resolve(config.baseUrl, this.orgId, this.appId, type)
```

Turns out you can't exactly do that with more than two arguments? All I get is:

```
'%config.baseUrl%/%this.orgId%'
```

Is there a way to make it work with more than two args? Or is there another module or function I can use to do this?

---

Found a [module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-join) that can do this, but I'd rather there be a native way if possible?

Comment: Is using the [`join`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_path1_path2) method of the `path` module an option?

Comment: Don't think so - I don't think it reduces multiple `/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dose this work?

```
["aa/", "bb/", "cc/"].reduce(url.resolve)
'aa/bb/cc/'

["aa", "bb", "cc"].reduce((a,b) => url.resolve(a+"/",b))
'aa/bb/cc'
```